# PHP mp3 stream making trouble at joining point

Tags: php, audio

I have an audio stream, some audio file in hdd and some in online and code is,

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
$mime_type = "audio/mpeg";
header("Content-type: {$mime_type}");


$files[0] = "audio/abc def.mp3";
$files[1] = "http://www.bootstrap-template.com/templates/HTML5//300111377/audio/mp3/FrankSinatra-BarbaraStraizand-Crush.mp3";
$files[3] = "audio/ghij.mp3";
$files[4] = "http://193.111.141.116:8888/stream";
/*print_r(headers_list());
print_r(get_headers($files[3]));
print_r(getallheaders());
exit();*/
while (true)
{
    foreach ($files as $key => $value)
    {
        $filename = $value;
        if($fh = fopen("$filename","r"))
        { 
            while (!feof($fh))
            {
                echo fgets($fh); 
            }
            fclose($fh); 
        }

    }
}
```

with Firefox it works fine (not in chrome and have not tested in other browsers) at the time of first song. It creates noise at the break point on 1st and second track and continues, at the time of 3rd track again it creates noise and not continues. There is nothing in error log. I am Using HTML5 player.

purpose of this script is, **to make stream running if `$file[4]` stops**

Comment: Please share your solution to this and tag me. i am stuck.

Comment: though i have completed the project successfully. And no more code available to me but I can suggest you to try https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9525-PHP-Serve-MP3-audio-files-to-play-from-a-playlist.html this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html5 player to play your files. in chrome use there builtin flash player uc browser as same. in Firefox use adobi flash. in this coz you can't play your files.

Comment: already i am using that player. i have updated my question. thanks.